# Which is stronger ? Picric acid or phoshoric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I would like  to have clarity as to which acid is the stronger acid; picric acid or phosphoric acid.
Because different  sources are giving me different  answers

Answer (score 2):

Where are you getting your data?

Picric acid is the stronger, pKa 0.38 [data here](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB1195194.htm)

The first pKa for phosphoric acid is 2.15 [data here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Phosphoric_acid#section=Dissociation-Constants). Remember that phosphoric acid is a tribasic acid so there are 3 dissociation constants, one for each acidic proton.